# Python Conditionally Add Class to <td> Tags in HTML Table

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have some data in the form of a csv file that I'm reading into Python and converting to an HTML table using Pandas.

Heres some example data:

```
name  threshold  col1 col2 col3
A     10         12   9    13
B     15         18   17   23
C     20         19   22   25
```

And some code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
table = df.to_html(index=False)
```

This creates the following HTML:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>name</th>
      <th>threshold</th>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

No I want to conditionally add a class to each cell in the html table if its value is less than a certain threshold. The threshold is different for each row in the table.

So given the example data above, I want to add a class, class="custom" to cell col2 with name A and to cell col1 with name C.  In CSS, I will then fill the cell color as red if it has the "custom" class.

The result would be something like:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>name</th>
      <th>threshold</th>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td class="custom">9</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td class="custom">19</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can this be achieved using Beautiful Soup?

Answer (score 1):

Using  *BeautifulSoup* you can add a class to the tags attrs as you would set a key/value in a dictionary:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

for row in soup.select("tbody tr"):
    tds = row.find_all("td")     
    if int(tds[3].text) < int(tds[1].text):
        tds[3]["class"] = "custom"
     if int(tds[2].text) < int(tds[1].text):
        tds[2]["class"] = "custom"
```

Which using your input html would give you:

```
<html><body><table border="1" class="dataframe">
<thead>
<tr style="text-align: right;">
<th>name</th>
<th>threshold</th>
<th>col1</th>
<th>col2</th>
<th>col3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>12</td>
<td class="custom">9</td>
<td>13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>B</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>23</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>C</td>
<td>20</td>
<td class="custom">19</td>
<td>22</td>
<td>25</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table></body></html>
```

Just use whatever it is in the if that decides whether to add it or not.

Comment: In my case, df.to_html() returns a type unicode, since my df is a dataframe. Then I cant use "html.parser" in the Beautiful Soup function. The criteria, which I mentioned above, is if the value is less than the value in the threshold column of that row, then add the "custom" class, otherwise do nothing and go on to the next one.

Comment: When using BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") I get the error:  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'.  In my case, html is of type unicode, which is coming from:  html = pd.read_csv("data.csv").to_html(index=False)

Comment: You are doing something wrong as a td could never be text. What is the full traceback?

Comment: It seems the "html.parser" is causing the issue, if I just do BeautifulSoup(html), then its fine

Comment: So you have lxml installed also? It works fine for me so not sure why html.parser is choking for you.