# Converting float to string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas containing datetime and float data.

```
time                         price1              price2
2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z     1.4526547885        1.654775563
```

I need to convert the columns to string format such that the price1 and price2 columns shows number upto 4 decimal places and the time is displayed as: 01,02,2018  00:00:00

Any leads on this is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for formating `datetime`s and then custom format of `float`s:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.strftime('%Y,%m,%d %H:%M:%S')

cols = ['price1','price2']
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: '{0:.4f}'.format(x))
print (df)
                  time  price1  price2
0  2018,02,01 00:00:00  1.4527  1.6548
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the last two digits of price1 and price2 columns data to be bold and be of increased size?

Comment: I think not, it is not possible.

Comment: Possible solution is create html and modify it.

Comment: can you please share an example, if possible on how to do that

Comment: Not so easy, I need time.

Comment: It is really complicated, need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39600120/2901002) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15441779/2901002)

Comment: and convaert `df` to `html` before by `html = df.to_html()`

Comment: For single column you can use this:

`df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].apply(lambda x: '{0:.2f}'.format(x))`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the **[round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html)** method to show only 4 decimals. and use .**[apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html)**(str) to convert it to string object

**EX**:

```
df["price1"] = df["price1"].round(4).apply(str)
df["price2"] = df["price2"].round(4).apply(str)
```

Comment: I need those to be converted to string type too. similar for datetime

Comment: This will not work as desired if decimal is shorter then the rounded number i.e. for value 1.45 you will get formatted string 1.45 where expected value is 1.4500 when rounding is 4